# Как получить название класса после клика на элемент, у которого 2 родителя

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ребята ситуация такая, я хочу получить имя класса, по которому было кликнуто, что бы сделать определенные действия.

Вот структура:

```
<div class="block">
 <div class="cardline">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="title></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Я хочу что бы когда мышью кликнули именно в области блока с классом header - произошло действие. для этого, как я считаю мне нужно узнать имя класса на который было кликнуто. я уже пробовал массу способов но без результатно.

к примеру:

```
}).on(\'click\',function(){
    alert($(this).children().children().attr("class"))
    //выводит имя первого элемента который нашло, даже если я кликаю к примеру по блоку "title"
});
```

Comment: так почему бы не привязаться в классу header? или как понять, какой блок надо обрабатывать? тот, у которого ровно два родителя?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, в заголовке одно, в описании - другое, хотите получить - третье. Так можно получить класс того, куда тычешь $(document).click(function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).attr('class'))
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто отменяйте действие для других элементов :

```js
$("div").click(function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('class'));
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  block
 <div class="cardline">
   cardline
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="title">title</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что изменится если не отменять?

Comment: Щелкая на нижнем будут поочередно выполнены бинды для всех верхних элементов (в моем случае когда я вешаю бинды на все дивы)

Comment: @redroid, спасибо за помощь. Ваш код действительно работает, однако я теряю связь с группами. Вы мне помогли в прошлом вопросе, этот вопрос как продолжение прошлого. У вас в прошлом есть событие клика по группе для открытия спойлера. вот дело в том что там клик по всему блоку <div data-group="9"> который имеет дочерний <div class="cardline"> который в свою очередь <div class="cardheader">. Я хочу как раз открыть спойлер по клике на блок cardheader. Можете представить редактию предыдущего вопроса или как то подсказать как реализовать, так как этот пример не получился в конкретном случае

Comment: Я не знаю вашу структуру , но если у Вас вывод какого-то контента в том же виде что и указано в прошлом посте то надо всего лиш к верхнему элементу блока добавлять `data-group=<id>` , вы можете вкладывать элементы в элементы и они все равно будут разнесены по группам , вот пример с вашей версткой , хаотичным расположением и вложенностью https://jsfiddle.net/ypq2fafm/

Comment: Оно так и есть, притензий по работе нету вообще. Дело в том что группа присвоена родительскому блоку. А в нем есть множество дочерних и поддочерних элементов. Я хочу вызвать раскрытие скрипта по клике не на весь блок группы, а чисто на конкретный дочерний элемент. так как у меня есть другие элементы к примеру кнопка оций. и если я кликаю на нее то получается расскрывается группа, а не выпадает список опций.

Comment: Добавляйте в событие `e.preventDefault();return false;` это отменит клик по родительскому элементу (в примере который я дал выше так и есть , немного модифицированный код из прошлого поста)